# Delphi, find Object owner

Tags: delphi

In the following example code, is there any way to know if S has been added to MyStuff? (besides the obvious result of {whatever} or MyStuff.Contains())

```
Type TMyClass = Class
  a: string;
End;

    MyStuff: TObjectList<TMyClass>;

Var S: TMyClass;
begin
  MyStuff := TObjectList<TMyClass>.Create(True);
  S := TMyClass.Create;
  if {whatever} then MyStuff.Add(S);

  // who is the owner of s?
```

Comment: In the title and in the comment of the code snippet, you seem to ask if you can find the instance that holds a reference to an object. That's why you've got an answer addressing that but have accepted a totally unrelated answer.

Comment: You are looking for a boolean variable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object lifetime/ownership management is an art worthy of many books on the subject. And there are quite a few (sometime conflicting) approach to it.

But to get to your specific case, since your TMyClass doesn't have an Owner field, the approach I would choose would be looking like this :

```
Var S, vRef: TMyClass;
begin
  MyStuff := nil;
  S := TMyClass.Create;
  try
    vRef := S;
    MyStuff := TObjectList<TMyClass>.Create(True);
    if {whatever} then
    begin
      MyStuff.Add(S);
      S := nil; //You could also use a TRUE-initialized boolean variable and set it to False here to indicate that the object doesn't need to be freed...
    end;
    //vRef only usefull if you still need a reference to the object after this point.
  finally
    S.Free;
    MyStuff.Free;
  end;
```

I believe in ARC terminology, that would be akin to making S a strong reference, and vRef a weak reference.

There might be better solution to your problem, but from the limited context, that's what I'd come up with.

Comment: I'm confused, what does this have to do with the question, and why was it accepted?

Comment: @JerryDodge Because question was poorly worded. It was not really about owner, but what kind of logic can be applied to release object if it is not added to list. It seems like this was more question about program flow rather than ownership and from the beginning to the end pretty unclear one.

Comment: That's correct, that was my intention rather than owner, but it's more like "does it have an owner"

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, no. You'd have to explicitly add a field to keep track of this. A single object *could* potentially be a part of *many* different lists. Technically, even multiple lists which "owns" its objects (although would produce undesired behavior).

I have a habit of always adding a field for purposes such as this. For example...

```
type 
  TMyList = class;
  TMyClass = class;

  TMyList = TObjectList<TMyClass>;

  TMyClass = class(TObject)
  private
    FOwner: TMyList;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TMyList);
  end;

constructor TMyClass.Create(AOwner: TMyList);
begin
  FOwner:= AOwner;
end;
```

As a side-note, the term "owner" is typically used in cases where there is a very strict owner relationship. For example, when creating components, you provide it an "owner", which in turn is responsible for destroying it when the owner itself is destroyed.